# RegExp: How to match only letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been attempting to add this error check part in `var letters` for another 8 lines but it seems to completely destroy my entire error check when I add these lines.

**In summary**

---

```
var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
if(username.value.match(letters)) {
  myerror += "Username is good. <br>"; 
 } else {
  myerror += "Username can only have letters. <br>"; 
 }
```

**More context:**

---

```
<script>
    function valfunc() {

        var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var confirm = document.getElementById("confirm").value;
        var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
        var myerror = "";

        if (username.length == 0) {
            myerror += "Username field has been left blank. <br>";
        }

        if (password.length == 0) {
            myerror += "Password field has been left blank. <br>";
        }

        if (confirm.length == 0) {
            myerror += "Confirm field has been left blank. <br>";
        }

        if (age.length == 0) {
            myerror += "Age field has been left blank. <br>";
        }

        if ((username.length < 5) || (username.length > 15)) {
            myerror +=
                "Username should be between 5 and 15 characters long. <br>";
        }

        if (password !== confirm) {
            myerror += "Password and Confirm input text box values should match. <br>";
        }

        var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
        if (username.value.match(letters)) {
            myerror += "Username is good. <br>";
        } else {
            myerror += "Username can only have letters. <br>";
        }

        if (age <= 0) {
            myerror += "Age should be a positive integer. <br>";
        } else {
            if ((age < 18) || (age > 110)) {
                myerror += "Age should be between the values 18 and 110. <br>";
            }
        }

        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = myerror;

        if (myerror.length > 1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }
</script>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed  -->
</script>
```

Comment: example username vlaue?what error its showing?

Comment: is myerror declared earlier? do you have any errors in the browsers **developer** tools console - hint, you can `var letters = /^[a-z]+$/i;` for more concise code

Comment: in what sense does it "completely destroy"? remember, we can't see what your code does without those lines

Comment: myerror was initialized earlier. Myerror is part of several errors such as length check that worked fine. However once I add this part the whole code stops working. I am trying to post more code but this website is not allowing it due to formatting.

Comment: Is there a way to post a large amount of code quickly? w/o formatting it here line by line

Comment: You should post your code as a runnable snippet, preferably having reduced it to the **minimum** that displays the error. There is no need to include jQuery or any other library that isn't used by the posted code.

Comment: seeing as you **always** add to myerror, your logic dictates that you'll **always return false** - you're basically saying (unlike with every other test) that any username results in adding text to myerror, then at the end of the validation, you return false because the length of myerror is > 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the `username.value` use username.you are not using the exact `username.value` should be `undefined` it will throw error while you use
`username.value.match()`

```
var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
if(username.match(letters))
 {
  myerror += 
  "Username is good. <br>"; 
 }
 else{
  myerror += 
  "Username can only have letters. <br>"; 
 }
```

Comment: I think that qualifies as "*…a simple typographical error*", so good catch but voting to close. BTW, *username* will never be undefined. The initialiser may throw an error if `document.getElementById("username")` returns *null*, otherwise it will be a (possibly empty) string.

Comment: Ohhhhh. I see. Thank YOU! Also thanks to others that tried helping

Comment: you'll still return false from `valfunc` regardless

Comment: Yes, that part I still need to work on as well but the "value" was what was throwing off the entire myerror

Answer (score 0):

Here lies the error

```
if(username.value.match(letters))
```

`username` is string, not an object as you have already taken value from object here

```
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
```

thats why it is giving error, it should be

```
if(username.match(letters))
```